# Why is the C++ httplib library blocking my main thread after creating the server?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the C++ httplib library. It appears to be blocking my main thread, but I don't believe it always did this. My relevant code looks like this:

```
Server server;
String address = "192.168.1.200";
int port = 4000;

server.Get("/getAsset", [this](const Request& req, httplib::Response& res) 
{
    res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    auto info = getAssetData();
    res.set_content(GetResponse(info), "application/json");
});
server.listen(address.c_str(), port, 0);
```

I'm running the code above on my laptop, and my laptop's IP is 192.168.1.200, so the server is running on my computer. What's interesting is if I pass in an IP from some other network interface on my computer (i.e. 169.254.143.40), the server doesn't block the main thread anymore.

From looking at the source code in httplib, I did make an observation. Consider the source code in httplib, below:

```
inline bool Server::listen(const char *host, int port, int socket_flags) {
  if (bind_internal(host, port, socket_flags) < 0) return false;
  return listen_internal();
}
```

When I pass in my IP (192.168 ...), the code returns listen_internal().

When I pass in another IP from a different network interface on my laptop (169.254 ...), the code returns false.

Any ideas on why all of this is happening?

Comment: Possibly related note: 169.254.X.Y addresses are commonly used by DHCP as a placeholder when DHCP could NOT get an address. Make sure your laptop has a valid address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Server::listen` is intended to be blocking. As you see in the code, it tries to bind the port on the interface and if it succeeds, it listens indefinitely to accept clients.

If it cannot bind the interface (by example because it doesn't exists), the function will return `false` to indicate an error. The listen loop can also return an error if the socket becomes closed.

As usual the examples don't give the code for error handling. A more accurate sample would be:

```
if(!server.listen(address.c_str(), port, 0))
{
    std::cerr<<"Server stopped in error state\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

If you want to listen on all addresses, use `"0.0.0.0"` as the binding interface.